# Typings generated "~" modules

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using `typings` with a new React project. I've installed various library type definitions as `--global` from `dt`, like this:

```
typings install dt~redux --global --save
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and I've noticed that when it suggests to import something it finds it in a bunch of modules that start with `~`. What is this?

For example, if I ask for import suggestion on Redux [`IDispatch`](https://gist.github.com/ulfryk/69981ccfb488647b6ee3#file-redux-d-ts-L19) I get suggestions for:

```
~redux-thunk~redux/redux
~react-router-redux~redux/redux
~react-redux~redux/redux
~redux/redux
```

Which generate import statements like this:

```
import {IDispatch} from "~redux-thunk~redux/redux";
```

What I expect is:

```
import {IDispatch} from "redux";
```

What is going on here? Why does `typings` generate these modules with `~` in them? What is the intended usage of those modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, declaration files depend on other declaration files. Think eg. about `redux-form`: you are using types in your declaration file that are specific for `redux` and you don't want to redeclare these. You should just be able to import them. There are two ways typings handles these:

- if you install a **global declaration file**, eg. the DefinitelyTyped version of `redux-form` (`typings install --global dt~redux-form`). During installation, typings will tell you it stripped some references. Then it is up to you to also install these. Otherwise, the declaration file you just installed is probably invalid, as it is using type declarations from eg. the redux declaration file.
- if you install a **module declaration file**, eg. the typings registry version of `redux-form`, (`typings install npm~redux-form`) typings has a much better understanding on which other declaration files this one depends. As a result, it can generate a declaration file that contains the full declaration files on which the installed one depends. It'll put these in 'pseudo' modules so they can be used inside the same declaration file.

  Eg for `redux-form`, the generated `typings/modules/redux-form/index.d.ts` file will include

  ```
  declare module '~redux-form~redux' { /* actual redux typings */ }
  ```

  And further down, inside the `redux-form` module declaration, you'll see:

  ```
  import { IDispatch as Dispatch, IReducer as Reducer } from '~redux-form~redux';
  ```

  while [the original](https://github.com/asvetliakov/typings-redux-form/blob/e77e0843946deca9e65174c9ddeec95e00899114/index.d.ts#L8) is just importing from redux.

  The drawback: this creates some module `~redux-form~redux` from which typescript could think you can import types from. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` However, it should be possible now to just import whatever you need from `redux-form`. (`import * as reduxForm from 'redux-form'`)

Comment: This makes sense... but if I try `import {IDispatch} from "redux"` and declare `dispatch: IDispatch`, I cannot pass a function to `dispatch()` as is allowed by `redux-thunk`, because vanilla `redux` does not know you can do this. It works if I `import {IDispatch} from "~redux-thunk~redux"` but I don't really like this...